# Pagination: Having Previous/Next navigation on top of page as well

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This might be a duplicate question, but I did not find one in meta. If there is one, then please direct me accordingly.

When we see the latest questions for a particular tag, and say for example, setting is to show 50 questions per page, we will either have to scroll all the way to the bottom (also achieved by shortcut keys) to navigate to a previous/next page to see more questions.

[image: pagination]

Will it add value to have the pagination items (previous/next) at the top of the page as well?

Comment: I agree that it would.

Comment: This a good request because returning from a question always lands you on the first page for your tag.  As this [Browser history pagination doesn't remember the page I was at...] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313878/browser-history-pagination-doesnt-remember-the-page-i-was-at-when-navigating-b) hasn't gained traction, a page navigation bar at the top would be useful.