# Browser history/pagination doesn't remember the page I was at (when navigating back from a question)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav, question-lists, pagination

This applies to all the pages with pagination (for example, just the "Home").

1. Use the pagination to go to any other page than page 1

   [image: Pagination]
2. Click a question in the new page

   [image: Random question on page 5]
3. Navigate back from the question
4. You are back at page 1 (with the same scroll position even)

   [image: Back at page one]

Obvious workaround is to open the pages in new tabs, but sometimes you want just to open a question to peek in and then return back. Happens at least on Chrome 47.

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312885/new-nav-page-size-resets-when-changing-pages-on-a-new-page This is likely because, in response to [some other issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312524/2607247) that came up a short-ish while ago, if you click on a page the url no longer displays what page you're on, what page size, etc. Since in your browser's history the link is now just the generic tab page (e.g. stackoverflow.com/questions) it can't take you to the correct page. (And probably to the correct page size, but I'd have to test that.)

Comment: I couldn't repro this - everything functions fine.

Comment: @nicael I just did some testing and it is borked when you are logged in, but not when you are logged out. Browsing the full list of questions when logged out properly updates the state with query strings (http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest) when trying logged in the state just stays as http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I was just going to post a similar question as I experience this problem while logged in via Internet Explorer. I think it could be resolved by saving the current page/sort/filters in localStorage and then reapplying from there when applicable.

Comment: @nicael Hi - what browser are you using? I'm using Opera and have this problem. It also happens when using Edge

Comment: Is there a fix or even an official bug/jira raised for this? - really annoying

Comment: Getting same problem either, the problem has still not fixed yet.

Comment: It seems to be better now. You are on the correct page after navigation back from a question. (But a "reload" goes to the first page, no matter where you are.)

Comment: @MartinR No, I still see the same problem, navigating back from a question takes me to the first page. It's been well over a year, how come such a basic problem hasn't been solved?

Comment: I experience the exact same problem as well, still. It's 2017, surely paging in a web application cannot be this hard to get right?

Comment: With [the death of New Nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0), this issue no longer occurs; we'll try & do a better job of avoiding it in New New Nav.

Comment: @Shog9 isn't the current new nav the new new new nav?

Comment: Well, the current new nav is the old nav, the one that predated the old new nav, but with a sidebar instead of a top bar. So I guess it's the new old nav. But we'll eventually have a new new nav, based on the new old nav, or effectively an all-new new new old nav. I think we should name it "Bob" for short.

Answer (score 0):

We've got through several iterations of revising the question lists and I just can't get this to repro under any scenario. I'm going to tag this status-completed as it was likely a transient bug we inadvertently fixed but I'll change it back and dig if anyone can still repro and give details here.