# Browser back button not working properly in Firefox while viewing questions

Tags: discussion, bug, firefox

In **Mozilla Firefox** suppose I am viewing **Page Number 5** from the questions list and then I opened one of the questions from that page, then, when I pressed back button from browser address bar then it takes me back to **Page Number 1**  instead of **Page Number 5**. This thing works perfectly in Google Chrome Browser though.

**System Specs:**

Windows 10

**Browsers:** Firefox 50.1.0, Chrome

Here is a gif recorded for the same

[Error GIF](http://g.recordit.co/YXbd8WEOan.gif)

Comment: Seems to work for me on Firefox 50 on Ubuntu

Comment: not in windows though

Comment: Which version of Firefox ?

Comment: added in question though 50.1.0

Comment: It works for me in Waterfox on Windows. Can't imagine why it'd be different in Firefox.

Comment: Works for me with Firefox 50.1.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: not working for me though. Go to last page and enter any question from that page, and then click back button and then it opens the first page.

Comment: @CodyGray added a gif for the same. Please check

Comment: What do you see when you right-click the *back* button? Does the second entry point to the page you last loaded, or does it point to page 1? What happens when you use the Backspace key instead of clicking the button, does it work correctly then?

Comment: @Stijn on back button click as well as backspace click I always see page 1.

Comment: OK, try with a clean profile then and see if you still have the problem. If it disappears, try disabling the extensions of your current profile.

Comment: @Stijn clean profile means? Clearing cache?

Comment: See [Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), just follow the steps to create a new profile. (Don't delete your current one!)

Comment: @Stijin It works in new profile but doesn't work even after disabling all extensions in current profile

Comment: Well this confuses me to no end, because the jump-to-page-1 happens for me too... in Chrome on two different OSes. Both the SO main page and the meta question list do it, only the site search preserves page numbers on navigating back to it. And I thought that was quite normal since the question list pagination bars don't alter the URL in any way.

Comment: @Stijn: seems to work here...

Comment: Vivek and @Gimby: do you perhaps use the new navigation? That one has [a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313878/browser-history-pagination-doesnt-remember-the-page-i-was-at-when-navigating-b). For Vivek, I guess you didn't log in with the new Firefox profile when testing, which would explain what's happening.

Comment: so I have to login with the new profile too? I tried without logging in

Comment: @VivekMishra Yeah, when not logged in you don't use the new navigation. You should be able to reproduce it when logging in. Or just check your profile settings and see if you have opted in for the new navigation.

Comment: Yes after login it is happening in new profile too.

Comment: @stijn yes I do use the new navigation.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a session/storage issue and it needs to be addressed inside Javascript. I had this issue before, and I had to add compatibility checks, as history sessions are handled differently by different browsers.

It could also be an extension or a module.

Just FYI, it works as expected for me, both with enabled and disabled extensions.