# Is pagination and the back button supposed to be broken?

Tags: support, pagination

As I am reading through lots of questions regarding specific topics I've noticed that pagination seems to be broken and this also seems to happen on the front page.

Let me explain.

1. Do a search for a tag that has more than one page of questions, such as [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git).
2. Observe which questions are the first 3 questions, just to have a point of reference
3. Navigate to page two, notice that new questions appear (yay)
4. Click on a question to read it
5. Hit the back button in the browser
6. Observe that you're back to page 1 (nay!)

   - *you will see the questions you noticed in point 2 above, not the ones you observed in point 3*

My expectation for the last entry there is that this shouldn't happen. I should be back to page 2 of my search results.

This exact same thing happens on the front page, once you hit back the browser takes you back to page 1.

I assume this is because the pagination is done in-page by just rewriting the dom, and not altering the URL in any way but is this really good behavior for a website in 2017? When did we obsolete the functionality of the back button?

I notice that if I manually edit the URL of the front page, for instance to http://stackoverflow.com?page=5, it correctly shows page 5 at the bottom with page 5 questions on the page.

However, this does not work for searching or the tagged-with link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?page=5 which goes back to showing page 1 navigation and content.

In any case, clicking on any of the navigation buttons at the bottom after using such an URL does not edit the URL in any way.

Comment: sounds like this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313878/browser-history-pagination-doesnt-remember-the-page-i-was-at-when-navigating-b?rq=1  tl;dr; yes, navigation with the back button is broken, for some 6 to 8 weeks now, minimum. However, if they fix it, they'll break my workflow ...

Comment: I voted to close it as a duplicate as well since I now see that there are multiple duplicates of this question on the meta site. However, it doesn't seem that any of those questions have an *answer*. Is it possible to get an official answer to this? Is someone looking into it? Because "we know it is broken" is not really helpful.

Comment: This has been an issue for a long time. I asked a similar question on MSE December, 2015! (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272043/paging-setting-is-not-remembered-on-custom-search-tab) I agree it isn't helpful, and am at a loss why something so simple has been around as a bug for so long.